# detecting change in variance with age

Tags: heteroscedasticity

I have some data on some measure of performance for a group of participants of different ages (11-30 years). The scatterplot suggests that the variance changes over that time, with a wide range of scores in younger participants and a narrower range of scores in older participants. The scores at the top of the range don't vary much with age, but the lower scores get higher with age. Sorry for the poor description - a graph would help here, but I hope you get what I mean.

Linear regression tells me that there is a significant relationships between age and mean performance (i.e., performance improves with age).

What I want to know is how to formally test for a change in the variance with age. Can I just do a linear regression through the lowest values in each of, say, 10 equal age bands and show that there is a significant increase? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few possibilities. I'll mention just a couple.

- You might fit a heteroskedastic regression, perhaps via REML. These can be fitted in a number of packages. (In R you can fit them with `remlscore` in `statmod`.)
- You might look at quantile regression, say a high quantile and a low quantile; the  slopes of the two quantiles can be considered as modelling the spread. Again, quantile regression can be done in a number of packages. (In R you can fit these with `rq` in `quantreg`, for example).